# Django cache database value in view function

Tags: django

I'm making an app that allows user to capture Google Sheet as image and send it into our company's chat service as an alert. So I save google sheet api credentials in database, and when user clicks "Run" button in web UI, it triggers an ajax request which runs a function in views.py to start capturing. If the credentials expire, this function will refresh to get new credentials and update new values in database.

But the problem is that when old credentials expires and is replaced by new credentials, function in view.py still use old credentials in database so it failed because wrong credentials. I think the reason is Django is caching old value in database, but don't know how to clear cache before getting value from database.

I have a main app called ggchat. I use docker, gunicorn, nginx and celery to deploy this app.

My function in views.py:

```
...
from lib.custom import capture_gs

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def run_task(request):
    task_id = request.GET.get('task_id', None)
    capture_gs(task_id)
    ...
```

The function capture_gs is from a local package. Below is the code for this package:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from mysite.models import Gstoken
from ggchat.models import Task
import datetime as dt
from lib.chat import upload_file

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

# Get token from db, create credential for gsheet oauth. If not found token from db, create db from file token.json
try:
    gstoken = Gstoken.objects.get(email='abc@gmail.com')
    creds = Credentials(token = gstoken.token, refresh_token=gstoken.refresh_token, token_uri=gstoken.token_uri, client_id=gstoken.client_id, client_secret=gstoken.client_secret, expiry = gstoken.expiry.replace(tzinfo=None), scopes=SCOPES)
except:
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/app/lib/credentials/google/sheet/token.json', SCOPES)
    # comment in first docker run
    gstoken = Gstoken.objects.create(email='abc@gmail.com', token=creds.token, refresh_token=creds.refresh_token, token_uri=creds.token_uri, client_id=creds.client_id, client_secret=creds.client_secret, expiry = creds.expiry + dt.timedelta(hours=7))
    

# If token is outdated, refresh and update into db. If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds.valid:
    creds.refresh(Request())
    # comment in first docker run
    try:
        gstoken.token = creds.token
        gstoken.expiry = creds.expiry + dt.timedelta(hours=7)
        gstoken.save()
    except:
        pass

def get_auth_token():
    return creds.token

def get_pdf(spreadsheet_id, **kwargs):
    """
    Return a screenshot pdf object from spreadsheet
    """
    url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheet_id + "/export"
    params = {"format":"pdf", "vertical_alignment": "MIDDLE", "horizontal_alignment": "CENTER", "fzr": "false", "fzc": "false", "gridlines": "false"} # default params
    params.update(kwargs)
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + get_auth_token()}
    return requests.get(url, params = params, headers = headers)

def capture_gs(task_id):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    r = get_pdf(task.ss_id, gid = task.gid, range = task.gs_range, scale = 4)
    pdf_file = '/app/temp/result.pdf'
    with open(pdf_file, 'wb') as saveFile:
        saveFile.write(r.content)

    upload_file(channel_name=task.channel, message=task.message, file_path=pdf_file)
```

Because it still uses the old credential, function get_pdf returns a corrupt pdf file with 401 unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The code that check and refresh the credentials should be in a function, and then you call that check-refresh function in other functions to avoid cache credentials. So I rewrite the local package as below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from mysite.models import Gstoken
import datetime as dt

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

def create_get_refresh_token():
    
    # Get token from db, create credential for gsheet oauth. If not found token from db, create db from file token.json
    try:
        gstoken = Gstoken.objects.get(email='abc@gmail.com')
        creds = Credentials(token = gstoken.token, refresh_token=gstoken.refresh_token, token_uri=gstoken.token_uri, client_id=gstoken.client_id, client_secret=gstoken.client_secret, expiry = gstoken.expiry.replace(tzinfo=None), scopes=SCOPES)
    except:
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/app/lib/credentials/google/sheet/token.json', SCOPES)
        # comment in first docker run
        try:
            gstoken = Gstoken.objects.create(email='abc@gmail.com', token=creds.token, refresh_token=creds.refresh_token, token_uri=creds.token_uri, client_id=creds.client_id, client_secret=creds.client_secret, expiry = creds.expiry + dt.timedelta(hours=7))
        except:
            pass

    # If token is outdated, refresh and update into db. If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds.valid:
        creds.refresh(Request())
        # comment in first docker run
        try:
            gstoken.token = creds.token
            gstoken.expiry = creds.expiry + dt.timedelta(hours=7)
            gstoken.save()
        except:
            pass

def create_service():
    create_get_refresh_token()
    gstoken = Gstoken.objects.get(email='abc@gmail.com')
    # create a service to connect to google sheet
    return build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=Credentials(token = gstoken.token, refresh_token=gstoken.refresh_token, token_uri=gstoken.token_uri, client_id=gstoken.client_id, client_secret=gstoken.client_secret, expiry = gstoken.expiry.replace(tzinfo=None), scopes=SCOPES))

def get_auth_token():
    create_get_refresh_token()
    return Gstoken.objects.get(email='abc@gmail.com').token

def get_pdf(spreadsheet_id, **kwargs):
    """
    Return a screenshot pdf object from spreadsheet
    """
    url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheet_id + "/export"
    params = {"format":"pdf", "vertical_alignment": "MIDDLE", "horizontal_alignment": "CENTER", "fzr": "false", "fzc": "false", "gridlines": "false"} # default params
    params.update(kwargs)
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + get_auth_token()}
    return requests.get(url, params = params, headers = headers)

def capture_gs(task_id):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    r = get_pdf(task.ss_id, gid = task.gid, range = task.gs_range, scale = 4)
    pdf_file = '/app/temp/result.pdf'
    with open(pdf_file, 'wb') as saveFile:
        saveFile.write(r.content)

    upload_file(channel_name=task.channel, message=task.message, file_path=pdf_file)
```